# GoDaddy - Wordpress Site Hosting Issues

Tags: wordpress, hosting, media, shared-hosting

I am using GoDaddy Windows Shared Hosting Server to host my WordPress Website. I am NOT using GoDaddy Managed WordPress service (I just copied my files on server, created DB and site works). However, I am facing some issues as follows :

1. Permalinks do not seem to work - Despite of the fix in .htaccess file for mod_rewrite module OR resetting the Permalink option via Admin Dashboard.
2. Cannot upload media : I get an error "Cannot upload media to wp-content/uploads" - If I set the upload_path in DB from BLANK to the above path, still the error continues.

To check if I have DB Connection issues: I tried to create a POST and I could do it well. Just that I could not upload MEDIA.

GoDaddy tech support is NOT able to resolve these issues.Meaning their solutions do not seem to work for me. Can anyone help me with my issues ?

Comment: Welcome to Godaddy ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

1- For the first issue I suggest to use the default wordpress htaccess file which is as following :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

after this go to Wordpress setting and save permalinks again.

2- for second is a privilege issue, download FTP software ,  ex: "filezilla", connect to your host and browse to `uploads` folder, right click to 'permissions' and put the privilege as 777

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try to fix your issue with

`# BEGIN WordPress
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /stage/
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /stage/index.php [L]
    
    # END WordPress`

2. It seems this is permission issue. Please kindly ask your hosting provider to give full permission for you